# How to ensure an Angular Custom Directive which clones a section containing a ng-repeat compiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an angular directive on a table, which wraps the original element in a div. It also clones the table body from the original element, and creates a new table element and appends the cloned body to the new table element, which gets appended to the wrapping div.

This normally works fine, however we've spotted that where there is an ng-repeat inside the body of the original element e.g repeating the rows, then it fails to work.

I've tried compiling the cloned body element but that makes no difference. I've also tried giving the directive a higher priority than ng-repeat, so that the directive runs first, however that's not made any difference either.

Any idea on what else I can try to fix this?

Comment: Need to show some code if you want help. Enough to see scopes at play. A scaled down minimal demo that replicates problem would also help

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, I meant to do this, however then came across the issue and a way to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had been putting all the code in the Link function. Came across an interesting article [compile and link functions inside AngularJS directives](http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/) by Jurgen Van de Moere which was very helpful. I've now created a separate compile and post link function. I also found I was able to put Angular into an Infinite Compilation Loop (yes!) which was being caused by inserting a new element before the directive element inside of the compile function. If however you insert the new element after the directive element, then Angular is happy with it and it works fine.